# How do I vertically center an input/textarea element where multiple lines of text still wrap below?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, input, textarea

I am using Ionic 3 so the element in question is a  inside of an  that I am styling (Originally I had an  inside of an  but since there is absolutely no way to wrap a single line input element I am forced to use textarea).
I need to be able to have a textarea element (I don't care how many rows) where a user can type multiple lines of text. BUT I also need the start of that text to be at the exact center of the textarea element (to line up with other elements constructing the overall thing.

[input vs textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vhGu.jpg)

The heights on these are percentage values so trying line-height, vertical-align and similar hasn't been successful. I tried display: flex and centering also display: table-cell and vertically aligning and no dice on either of those. Since it is web and mobile application I was also unsuccessful in padding-top because of the varying platforms.

I would like to have the beginning of the text within the text area start at the center of the text area so it aligns with the other content as in the above images, but also be able to wrap to new lines as the text becomes longer than the width of the text area.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured this out actually and it appears to work on both web and mobile.
Here is the code...

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const textarea: HTMLHtmlElement = window.document.querySelector('.wizard_statement_text');
  const lineHeight = Number(window.getComputedStyle(textarea).lineHeight.slice(0, -2));
  const h = textarea.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const top = h/2 - lineHeight/2;
  textarea.style.paddingTop = `${top}px`;
}, 100);
```

Basically I need the setTimeout to get the correct getBoundingClientRect value for the height of the textarea. Then I cut that in half for the true middle. I also need the actual line height of the text area and cut that in half as well to subtract to get the actual top of where I want the text area to be. Setting the paddingTop to that value seems to line up nicely.